# PDO doesn't find the column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I've created a class that extends `PDO` functionality for interact with the database. Until now all working pretty well, but I'm not able to execute the `update` statement on the query below:

```
$result = $this->db->update('table1', $postData['parameters'], "code = {$postData['code']}");
```

the array `postData` have this content:

```
$postData = array(
    "code" => "T941",
    "parameters" => array("description" => "Testing")
);
```

The `update` method available in my `db` class that extends the `PDO` functions, is this:

```
public function update($table, $data, $where)
{
    ksort($data);
    $fieldDetails = NULL; 

    foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $fieldDetails .= "`$key`=:$key,";
    }

    $fieldDetails = rtrim($fieldDetails, ",");  
    $sth = $this->prepare("UPDATE $table SET $fieldDetails WHERE $where");

    foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $sth->bindValue(":$key", $value);
    }
    return $sth->execute();
}
```

this method has always worked but now I get this error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'T941' in 'where clause'

Now I tried to dump the content of `update` like this:

```
1. echo $table;
2. var_dump($data);
3. echo $where;
```

and I get:

```
1. table1
2. array(2) {
   ["code"]=>
     string(4) "T941"
     ["description"]=>
     string(4) "Test"
   }
3. code = T941
```

The problem is that the `update` method doesn't access to the column name, but on the value! I really don't know why, in other classes I use it in the same way and working well.

This is the `table1` structure:

```
| code | description | lastUpdated |
```

what happean?

Comment: `$fieldDetails .= "`$key`=:$key,";` need to be `$fieldDetails .= "$key=:$key,";`

Comment: @Anant and if I have the need to have a column that has a default name busy? Do I have to add the quotes, so I need to use it in my way. Also I get the same error with your hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add quotes here :

```
code = {$postData['code']}
```

Change it to :

```
code = '{$postData['code']}'
```

That's simplest. Another advice is to use bindValue, to bind parameters to $where variable as well.

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten to escape them.

Comment: @NikolayTomitov Unfortunately `PhpStorm` tell me `Expected ]`, bad syntax so. I don't thinks is this the problem. As I said in other classes with the same way working.

Comment: Can you try to echo this expression :"code = {$postData['code']}". I think it is: code = T941. When you put this in WHERE clause of update it searches for a column named T941 and raises you an error. I'm sorry if I'm wrong but that doesn't look clear for me.

Comment: @NikolayTomitov I already wrote this in the question, if you read better this expression `code = {$postData['code']}` return `code = T941` that is the value of the `where` clause.

Comment: Exactly! You have to change it to code = 'T941' or it will search for a column named T941.

Comment: You may try to run the SQL query in some editor to test it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106646/discussion-between-dillinger-and-nikolay-tomitov).